# Retrieve individual values in tuple without brackets | Python | Flask | SQLALCHEMY | Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Using a database to retrieve project numbers and put them in a search for a user in a form. I am using an api (ajax google api) for autocompletion on the search.
[When putting it as autocomplete in search field it contains brackets and a comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rgOF.png)

I need it just to be like:

24403
24429

not like:

(24403,)
(24429,)

I am unsure how to do this. My current code is:

```
app.py 

class Element(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'elements'
ProjectNumber = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def basicTemplate():
    project_number = Element.query.with_entities(Element.ProjectNumber).distinct()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('search.html', navigation=project_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
base.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static\style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}- base</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
        {% block project_number %} {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
search.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
{% block project_number %}
<label for="project_code">Project Number</label><input type="text" id="project_code" name="project_code">
          <input type="submit">
          <script>
              $( function() {
                var project = [
                    {% for test in navigation %}
                        "{{test}}",
                    {% endfor %}
                ];
                $( "#project_code" ).autocomplete({
                  source: project
                });
              } );
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `with_entities` always returns a list of tuples.
You can combine multiple jinja filters to get a list of strings that can be passed directly to javascript.

First you extract the first element of all tuples and convert them into strings. You convert the received generator into a list and output it in a javascript-compatible manner.

```js
$(function() {
    const projects = {{ navigation | map('first') | map('string') | list | tojson }};
    $('#project_code').autocomplete({
        source: projects
    });
});
```

Of course you can also perform the extraction and conversion to the string in the endpoint.

Depending on how many projects are stored in your database, I recommend getting the data via ajax.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#project_code').autocomplete({
        source: '/search',
    });
});
```

```py
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    term = request.args.get('term', '')
    projects = Element.query.filter(Element.ProjectNumber.ilike(f'%{term}%')).all()
    return jsonify([str(p.ProjectNumber) for p in projects])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't know I actually needed to use something like tuple_containter[0][0] as its a 2d tuple which worked